# taking difference of tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have following tables;

```
 A   B                       A   B
 _____                       _____
 1   t                       7   a
 2   r                       5   d
 3   e                       3   e
 4   f
 5   d
 6   s
 7   a
```

And, output should be ;

```
 A   B                     
 _____                     
 1   t                      
 2   r                     

 4   f

 6   s
```

In other words I want difference of these two tables . I want region A in [this figure](http://www.budaconsulting.com/Portals/52677/images/venn.png).
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 USING (A, B)
WHERE t2.A IS NULL
```

Comment: Column `A` probably also needs to be equal and in the join condition.

Comment: You are, right, but the question somehow does not specify it :) I'll edit the answer anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

without using `JOIN`

```
SELECT A, B
FROM tableA
WHERE A NOT IN
    (SELECT Distinct A FROM tableB)
```

Comment: I like this . . . DIdn't know you could do it this way. Nice answer! +1

Comment: Column `B` probably also need to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    A, 
    B 
FROM Table_1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT Table_2.A AS Test
        FROM Table_2 
        INNER JOIN Table_1 AS T ON Table_2.A = Table_1.A
    )
```

Comment: Johntotetwoo's answer does the same thing, in a more elegant manner. I just learned something new . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, B 
  FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT A, B 
  FROM Table2;
```